# Short Story based on DNA amino acid cipher

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I'm looking for the name and author of a short story, probably in the 1980s or 1990s in one of the SF magazines, possibly Asimov's but I'm not sure about that.

A lawyer asks an undergraduate in biochemistry with an interest in cryptography to try to solve a cipher that was left by a murdered researcher.  She was picked because her background was similar to the researcher.  Though the researcher had a passing interest in cryptography, she had very little time to encipher her data before she was murdered.  The lawyer thought someone with a similar background would be able to decode what she did.

The cipher is based on the three-letter codes for amino acids.  There are 64 possible codes, which code for the various (I believe 20) amino acids.  Some amino acids have two or more three-letter codes.  You first need to translate the 64 three-letter codes into the amino acid they code for, then solve the 20 amino acids as a simple substitution cipher.

When the attorney for the other side says that there is no substitution for "x", she replies that "c-k-s" made an acceptable substitute.

Comment: Would you be able to weigh in on the discussion of the answer. Is the undergraduate the same as the pizza delivery girl below?

Comment: Yeah, that is something that confuses me. Is the undergrad merely disguised as a pizza delivery girl?

Comment: The undergrad was disguised as a pizza girl in order to gain access to the courtroom so she could deliver the deciphered text.  It was suggested by the person who asked her to decipher the text.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Harnessing Edlothiad's comment, this might be "[The GUAC Bug](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?82492)" by Charles L. Harness.

Here is [a plot summary](http://faculty.knox.edu/jdooley/Crypto/Crypto1.htm):

> Harness, Charles L. 1998. The GUAC Bug. Analog Science Fiction/Science Fact, 112-124.
> Ms. Hatfield, the pizza delivery girl, decrypts a cipher built into an RNA specimen. The message is a double encipherment of an RNA sequence, where the nucleides (G, U, A, and C) define amino acids. Each of the 20 amino acids then represents a letter of the alphabet in a simple monoalphabetic substitution. The message is used in a patent hearing to verify the author and authenticity of the RNA specimen. The pizza delivery girl is used to show that the cipher message is easy enough for a knowledgeable amateur to solve.

I don't see any mention of murder, but it does involve coding by amino acids and has a relative amateur doing the decoding.

It looks like it was only ever released in *Analog Science Fiction/Science Fact*.

Comment: Thwarted! I was afraid I wouldn't be able to get more of a background.

Comment: @Edlothiad: :) Ah, well you hadn't followed up on it, and I figured it was a close enough match as it was.

Comment: As said by the great philosophers of old, *You snooze, you lose*

Comment: GUAC is delicious.

Comment: this doesn't at all match the ops description.

Comment: @TheGreatDuck: They accepted it. As for not matching at all, I disagree. It involves an inexperienced person finding a message encoding in amino acids, and was published in a similar science fiction anthology to the one they remember. The other details might be a matter of either misremembering or the reviewer picking different aspects to describe.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots this sentence does not at all match up with that story. "A lawyer asks an undergraduate in biochemistry with an interest in cryptography to try to solve a cipher that was left by a murdered researcher." The person is not an undergrad. It is not for a murder investigation. *As the question is currently written,* this is not an answer.

Comment: @The GreatDuck  I never mentioned a murder investigation.  The researcher was (fatally) injured in the burglary of her lab/office.  She encrypted her research files.  The two-step code exactly matches what I remember. Code from 64 amino acid combinations of biochemical coding for 20 amino acids-->code of 20 amino acids-->relatively easy substitution cipher.
The "pizza girl" was a disguise to allow her to enter the courtroom (with the deciphered text in the pizza box) without her being named as an "expert witness".  If she could decipher the text, there was obviously no need for an "expert".

Comment: @TheGreatDuck, I don't understand how this isn't an answer. Regardless of how the question is written, this is an answer. Whether it's right or not, may be debatable, but it is an answer. Although it's rightness isn't even debatable, as the OP marked it as accepted and therefore confirmed that this is the story that they remember reading.

Comment: @Edlothiad well... that's not entirely true. If the answer does not clearly reflect what was written in the question, then the question either failed to convey itself properly or this isn't the correct question. If it isn't the correct question then it should be noted as such.

Comment: @YoshiBro Because you said "murdered" researcher I presumed that the story had some relevance to actually catching the person who murdered the researcher. Hence, I presumed the lawyer was looking to build evidence for a murder charge. It just seemed on a tangent for it to be about a patent hearing. Sorry.

Comment: @TheGreatDuck: We're starting to hit discussion levels in the comment thread, but in general, partial matches are encouraged on the site, both because the querent might have gotten it wrong and also because it provides a possible answer for people searching for similar works.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots fair enough. Still though. I was not intending to say this be deleted. I was merely pointing out its incorrectness for future reference.